Angular Material 3 - Menu and Select Options Not Changing
I have recently switched over to begin using the new Angular Material 3 Theming system using a multiple them approach. All seems to work fine on the components I am using except with the Select and Menu components.
I am able to switch the themes and the components all change to the color and typography of the selected theme, except the Options on the Select and Menu components. When they are shown they hold the theme that was applied when the app loaded. The font and colors do NOT change.
The first theme is applied with
@include mat.all-component-themes($sachub-theme);

Then using a CSS rule I apply a different theme by calling the MIXINS for the components I am using. Here is the lines for the Select Component. I call this MIXIN when the theme changes. This is a snippet, all components I use are placed in here, I have removed them here for simplicity sake.
@mixin extractComponentTheme($theme) {

  @include mat.menu-typography($theme);
  @include mat.menu-color($theme);


  @include mat.select-typography($theme);
  @include mat.select-color($theme);


}

ALL the other components change as expected, EXCEPT the Option and Menu items.
Any ideas?
